# Istio policy to deny expired JWT access tokens

Tags: istio

How can I define an Istio policy for my service to deny any request with a JWT access token that is expired?

For context, I have a Spring Boot KNative service with [RequestAuthentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/) config that has checks for the token issuer.

Answer (score 2):

Istio does that by default. Any JWT token that is expired, or otherwise invalid is denied by default.

However, for JWT token authorization to work, authorization policy must be configured.
<sub>[Source](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/#allow-requests-with-valid-jwt-and-list-typed-claims) for the below examples</sub>

1. Create `AuthorizationPolicy`

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: require-jwt
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       requestPrincipals: ["testing@secure.istio.io/testing@secure.istio.io"]
```

2. Get the valid JWT token

```text
TOKEN=$(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.11/security/tools/jwt/samples/demo.jwt -s) && echo "$TOKEN" | cut -d '.' -f2 - | base64 --decode -
```

3. Verify that the request with valid token is allowed

```text
kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" -c sleep -n foo -- curl "http://httpbin.foo:8000/headers" -sS -o /dev/null -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -w "%{http_code}\n"
```

*Adjust the above examples to your needs*

---

If, for some reason, Istio does allow expired or otherwise invalid tokens, you should check your previously applied policies, to make sure nothing overrides default behaviour.